# Invoke eclipse Java save actions from command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I have defined certain code format rules and save actions (as shown in the attached image) for my eclipse. I came across [this tutorial](http://www.peterfriese.de/formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter/) that allows me to format the code from command line using `org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter`. Can someone tell me which eclipse class I can use from **command line** to invoke the **save actions** functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there is no 'Eclipse Application' to run Clean-ups (or Save Actions) from command line.

Comment: @Deepak.Azad +1. However check this link http://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=90, if you look at the stacktrace " org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.CleanUpPostSaveListener.saved(CleanUpPo
stSaveListener.java:339)", the CleanUpPostSaveListener is formatting the code based upon save action. Can you let me know if we can leverage it

Comment: I think the main issue in running clean-ups from command line would be  to completely separate the UI parts from the non-UI parts. I have not looked at the code in detail to see how much work would that be.